# What kind of computers/laptops support the new orientation features of Firefox 3.6?

Tags: laptop, firefox, accelerometer

I just [downloaded Firefox 3.6 today](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/video/?video=whatsnew-3.6) and I noticed in the list of new features they have [an Orientation API](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/10/orientation-for-firefox/) that can detect the direction that your laptop/computer is tilted.  This is clearly a hardware feature of some sort, and I was just wondering if anybody knew a list of computers that would support such things.

Comment: I'm rather sure that I've only seen it on MACs on videos on the internet.  But that doesn't mean that those are the only kind of computer that support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reference I could find was [this ZDNet article](http://news.zdnet.co.uk/internet/0,1000000097,39805226,00.htm) that suggests recent MacBooks and some ThinkPads support it as well.